# How to add an extra field in the edit form in Flask Admin?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I want to add a field **projects** to my User edit form with Flask Admin.

To do so I tried to override the **edit_form** method to add the field as an additional attribute to the form, but the field is not added.

I cannot find any clear documentation about how to do add a field to the form in Flask Admin.

Anybody can help ?

```
class UserAdminView(ModelView):
    column_exclude_list = ['password',]    
    form_widget_args = {
        'password':{
            'disabled': True
        }
    }

    def edit_form(self, obj=None):
    form = super(UserAdminView, self).edit_form(obj)

    form.projects = sqla.fields.QuerySelectMultipleField(
        "Projects",
        query_factory=lambda: db.session.query(Project).join(UserProjectRel) \
        .filter(UserProjectRel.user_id==obj.id),
    )

    return form


class User(db.Model):  
    __tablename__ = 'phaunos_user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    confirmed_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)


class UserProjectRel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_project_rel'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('phaunos_user.id'), primary_key=True)
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_role = db.Column(ENUM(Role), nullable=False)

    user = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('user_project_rel', cascade='all'))
    project = db.relationship('Project', backref=db.backref('user_project_rel', cascade='all'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I first had to override get_edit_form:

```
class UserAdminView(ModelView):
    column_exclude_list = ['password',]
    form_excluded_columns = ['annotations', 'user_project_rel']
    form_widget_args = {
        'password':{
            'disabled': True
        }
    }

    def get_edit_form(self):
        form = super(UserAdminView, self).get_edit_form()
        form.projects = sqla.fields.QuerySelectMultipleField("Projects")
        return form

    def edit_form(self, obj=None):
        form = super(UserAdminView, self).edit_form(obj)
        form.projects.query = db.session.query(Project).join(UserProjectRel) \
            .filter(UserProjectRel.user_id==obj.id).all()
        form.projects.data = form.projects.query
        return form
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you missed the [`form_extra_fields`](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_extra_fields) attribute on `BaseModelView` class, so to add `project` input:

```
from wtforms.fields import TextField

class UserAdminView(ModelView):
...
    form_extra_fields = {
        'Projects': TextField('Projects')
    }
```

Comment: This would add a field to both the edit and create form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve it with `form_edit_rules` ([docs](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#customising-builtin-forms-via-rendering-rules)).
Documentations focuses only on `form_create_rules`, but if you want to interact with the edit form only, you can do it with the `form_edit_rules` property (it accepts a list of form field names and, of course, the newly created field).